# Finding repetitive characters in a linked list in C

Tags: search, linked-list, char

I am working in C and am storing strings in linked lists. One character for one node. I want to pass the head of the of the list and a key char, as a parameter in my find(), and issue a print statement every time the 'key' is found. I am doing this because, eventually I need to modify this function to find and delete the character every instance it is found.

So far, my function finds the 'key' and issues a print statement. But, it will only do it once. For example if my list is…. a->d->a->m->NULL, and my key is… 'a', it will issue a print statement only once. But I need it to issue a print statement n times the key occurs, in this case 'a' occurs twice.

Here is my current find()

```
void find(struct node *head, char key)
{

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->data == key)
        {
            printf("char has been found\n");
            return;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("sorry, char has not been found\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `return` statement in your `if`, delete it and the function will print `"char has been found\n"` for each key that matches.

But sentence `"sorry, char has not been found\n"` will also be printed so add a flag `found` that you set to true in your `if` and check it to print or not don't print `"sorry, char has not been found\n"`.

For example:

```c
void find(struct node *head, char key)
{
    int found = false;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->data == key)
        {
            printf("char has been found\n");
            found = true;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        printf("sorry, char has not been found\n");
    }
}
```

Edit :

```c
int    list_destroy(t_list *head, t_f_dtr f_dtr)
{
  t_list    *cur = NULL;
  t_list    *tmp = NULL;

  if (!head)
    return (list_error("Error: list_destroy(): head is NULL."));
  if (head->next)
  {
    cur = head->next;
    tmp = cur->next;
    while (tmp != head->next)
    {
      if (free_elem_data(cur, f_dtr) || free_for_list_destroy(cur))
        return (-1);
      cur = tmp;
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    if (free_elem_data(cur, f_dtr) || free_for_list_destroy(cur))
      return (-1);
  }
  if (free_for_list_destroy(head))
    return (-1);
  return (0);
}
```

It's a function from my generic circular doubly linked list so don't use it as is as your list is different.

Comment: wow, i feel stupid. that was real simple. next is deletion. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes the problem is evident but you don't see it, it happens to me too.

Comment: I am still having trouble deleting the multiple recurring nodes and returning the proper list. I can get the function to delete one of the occurrences, but not all.

Comment: You'll have to use a second pointer which is shifted of one element relative to the `head` because you can't do the `head = head->next;` after deleting `head`. I'll edit my answer and add an example.

Comment: thanks. I made some progress… ill update my code. many cases are still causing the function to not work properly. ill give examples in a minute

Comment: I'm not an experienced poster of stackoverflow but I think you should make another question. I believe the concept of stackoverflow is one question per topic.

Comment: No problem ;) yeah, you can't insert newlines in comments with [enter].

Answer (score 0):

The return statement stops the function from continuing on. You need to do something like this where you free the node so you don't have a memory leak, but also add a link between the previous node and the next node since the current node is being deleted.

```
void find(struct node *node, char key)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->data == key)
        {
            printf("char has been found\n");
            struct node *deleteMe = node;
            if(node->prev)
                node->prev = node->next;
            node = node->next;
            free(deleteMe);
        } else
            node = node->next;
    }
    printf("sorry, char has not been found\n");
}
```